# Popup window unrecognized by Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

Using Java, selenium and xpaths.  I am verifying a Citrix project.  Really all I have to do is login, show the favorites and apps buttons and that they are there.  I get this window, which blocks everything:

[image: I crossed out personal info]

And I can't do Selenium clicks until it is closed.  Problem is, inspect does not show it, there is not a new windowhandle to locate it, and trying to find any xpaths does not work.

I can continue by using javascript clicks to click items blocked by this view, but it gets annoying and they may not accept it.

Before you suggest it, we are not allowed to use Robot.  I looked for a Javascriptexecutor to just hit "ENTER" (since manually you can hit ENTER to download it) but couldn't find one.  Uasing Actions(driver) does not work either because I think the window is not recognized.

There is a link "already installed" which I can click (with javascriptexecutor) and continue, but the popup window stays visible.  Perhaps use Javascriptexecutor to open a link in a new window?  But I tried some things which didn't work, although perhaps I did not have the right idea.

Any suggestions?  BTW another solution that won't work is to do it manually the first time, because no matter how many times it runs and how many times the download button was clicked manually, the next time it comes up I get the window again.

Any ideas? (I scribbled out personal company info).  Oh, and it is not an Alert.  At least none recognized.

Comment: Check here for a registry setting that allows you to add a "remember" checkbox: https://www.considerit.co.uk/resources/chrome-wants-to-open-this-application/  (you can then accept it and remember the choice for a certain profile.... use that profile when running selenium.)

Comment: or, it sounds like you can set an option/preference for this... see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554564/bypass-external-protocol-request-popup-during-selenium-automation

Comment: I tried.  I could not find "#advanced-settings-expander".  I am using Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)