# How to automate this downloading prompt using python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I made a crawler for downloading torrent from a specific torrent site using selenium and python. The download will happen when someone clicks on the "magnet download" link and click on the "open μtorrent". So after clicking on the "magnet download" it will open a pop-up(which is not a javascript pop-up) and has to click on the "open μtorrent". How can I automate this step? I am attaching the image below. Please help me in this. I have looked for the solutions in stack but none of the answers helped me.

[image: image of the issue]

Comment: I think this is a standard alert, so you can use. 

alert = Alert(driver) 
# accept the alert 
alert.accept() 

Please let me know did this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it using the profile itself

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {'protocol_handler.allowed_origin_protocol_pairs': 
{"https://www.1377x.to":{"magnet": True}}})
d = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
d.get("http://example.com/url/to/magnet/site")
elem = d.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*=magnet]")
elem.click()
```